# how to fix unresponsive mic on webcam for ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sound, webcam, microphone

I bought a webcam and when I use zoom or cheese the video shows up but the mic isn't working. It is unresponsive and can't find any signs of life other than seeing mics listed in dropdown lists. The input level does not move when I look up the mic in `Sound->Input->Choose a device for sound input`. There are entries listed for mics here: `Digital Input (S/PDIF) - HD Webcam USB` and `Microphone - HD Webcam USB`. The webcam is a Dericam (model no. W3).

Here are the things I've tried:

1. I've gone into sound settings and I can see the webcam mic listed, but the input level bar doesn't respond to my voice. I don't have other mics as it is a desktop. I've tried increasing the volume but this doesn't help.
2. I downloaded `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol` but haven't managed to adjust settings to get it to work.
3. I've also done some googling and haven't been able to find a solution.

I don't know a lot about configuring these devices, so if there is more information I can provide to help you diagnose and solve the problem, let me know and I'll do my best.

Comment: Is there any button on your camera to turn on the mic? Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: There is no on/off switch for the mic. I ended up just buying an external mic.

Comment: For me the USB port itself are making problems, so I plugged in another port. Sometimes I have to unplug and plug again.